# How do I cut dvb-streams (mpeg) easily? DVBCut doesn't run in 11.10

Tags: 11.10, video-editor, dvb

On Ubuntu 11.04 Natty and older I used to cut streams recorded from [Me TV[image]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/me-tv) with [DVBcut[image]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/dvbcut). Though this package is in official repositories I can't use it because of missing the icons on the GUI and lacking the option to add it in the context menu for mpeg-files.

[image]

Installing a (higher) [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~bojo42/+archive/dvbcut)-version doesn't work due to dependencies.

When I use [Avidemux[image]](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/avidemux) I have struggle with an audio delay.

What can I do to have it as easy as before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took the [deb-file from another ppa](https://launchpad.net/~frafu/+archive/ppa/+packages). This works. Additionally I [created a .desktop-file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/105389/context-menu-within-firefox-doesnt-work-after-hiding-showing-window) to use this app via rightclick.

Only problem: When starting the app i miss the icons:

[image]

But it works, though. The icons appear later.